# Producing instrumented source using NYC provides a absolute path

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on functional code coverage so trying to run my web application on instrumented code. The command used is , `nyc instrument ./src ./dist` . This command is instrumenting my source files and assigning absolute file path like `path="C:\\Code\\nyc-proj\\src\\js\\index.js"`. So when i run my nyc coverage and try to generate lcov report it shows like below,

[image: Coverage Image]

I have to manually change the file path after instrumentation to relative path, like `path="js/index.js"` then it generates the proper report.

Is it possible to get the path as a relative path while instrumenting the code itself?